# How to replace special characters from a column using DUCK DB?

Tags: regex, regexp-replace, duckdb

I have below table in Duck Db. I want to replace the special characters in the column state with space. I used regex to do it but doesn't replace the special characters. What is the best way to replace the special characters in the columns using Regex?

Table :-

[image]

SQL Query:-

```
UPDATE test
SET State = REGEXP_REPLACE(State,'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', ' ')
WHERE State is not Null;
```

Output is same as the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the [`regexp_replace` function](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/functions/patternmatching#using-regexp_replace) only replaces the first occurrence of the regular expression. Use the global replace flag, `g`, as the fourth argument of `regexp_replace`:

```
UPDATE test
SET State = regexp_replace(State,'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', ' ', 'g')
WHERE State IS NOT NULL;
```